# View not bound correctly in using JSTL <form:select> tag in jsp

Tags: spring-mvc, jstl

`enter code here`I have a controller and below two urls mapped for GET and POST of a business object named Member.

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/usr/updateMember", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView findForEdit(@RequestParam("id") Integer id) {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("registration");
    try {
        List<City> cities = getGenericDao().getAllItems(City.class);
        List<Chapter> chapters = getGenericDao().getAllItems(Chapter.class);
        modelAndView.getModel().put("cities", cities);
        modelAndView.getModel().put("chapters", chapters);

        Member member = getGenericDao().getItem(Member.class, id);
        modelAndView.getModel().put("edit", true);
        modelAndView.getModel().put("loggedinuser", getPrincipal());
        modelAndView.getModel().put("roles", userRoleService.findAll());

        modelAndView.getModel().put("member", member);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return modelAndView;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/usr/updateMember", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String update(@ModelAttribute("member") Member member, BindingResult result, SessionStatus status) {
    getGenericDao().update(member);
    status.setComplete();
    return "redirect:/list.do";
}
```

My view is as follows:

```
<form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="member"
            class="horizForm">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-">
            <label class="col-md-3" for="name">Member
                Name</label>
            <div class="col-md">
                <form:input type="text" path="name" id="name"
                    class="form-control input-sm" />
                <div class="has-error">
                    <form:errors path="name" class="help" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    ...
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <label class="col-md-3" for="userRoles">Roles</label>
            <div class="col-md">
                 <form:select path="userRoles" items="${roles}" multiple="true"
                    itemValue="memberId" itemLabel="role"
                    class="form-control input-sm" />
                <div class="has-error">
                    <form:errors path="userRoles" class="help" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-">
        <label class="col-md-3 control-labl" for="chapter">Chapter</label>
        <div class="col-md-7">
            <%-- <form:select path="chapter.id" items="${chapters}" itemValue="id"
                itemLabel="name" class="form-control input-sm"> --%>
            <%-- <option value="-1">Select a Chapter</option>
                <c:forEach var="chp" items="${chapters}">
                    <option value="${chp.id}">${chp.name}</option>
                </c:forEach> --%>
            <%-- </form:select> --%>

            <form:select path="chapter" class="form-control input-sm">
                <!-- <option value="-1">Select a Chapter</option> -->
                <c:forEach var="chp" items="${chapters}">
                    <option value="${chp}">${chp.name}</option>
                </c:forEach>
            </form:select>

            <div class="has-error">
                <%-- <form:errors path="chapter.id" class="help-inline" /> --%>
                <form:errors path="chapter" class="help-inline" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

GET is working as expected and View is populated with expected values for String, List and Chapter type objects.

[GET Method working fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWJcL.jpg)

When I try to update the Member via POST it doesn't get values bound to List and Chapter objects and BindingResult has below values.

```
org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 3 errors
Field error in object 'member' on field 'chapter': rejected value [Chapter [chapterId=1, chapterName=SUPER]]; codes [typeMismatch.member.chapter,typeMismatch.chapter,typeMismatch.com.codex.survey.beans.Chapter,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [member.chapter,chapter]; arguments []; default message [chapter]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.codex.survey.beans.Chapter' for property 'chapter'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [com.codex.survey.beans.Chapter] for property 'chapter': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]
Field error in object 'member' on field 'userRoles': rejected value [2]; codes [typeMismatch.member.userRoles,typeMismatch.userRoles,typeMismatch.java.util.List,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [member.userRoles,userRoles]; arguments []; default message [userRoles]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.List' for property 'userRoles'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [com.codex.survey.beans.UserRole] for property 'userRoles[0]': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]
```

I am not able to figure what is going wrong here with view, please help me solve this issue.

Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike stateful, component based frameworks (for example JSF) Spring MVC cannot automatically convert raw HTTP parameters to the corresponding object type.

You thus need to register a converter to handle this and register it with the Spring context. There are various ways of doing this however one implementation would look like:

```
@Component
public class StringToChapterConverter implements Converter<String, Chapter> {

    @Autowired
    private ChaperService service;

    /**
     *chapterId is the HTTP post param passed in by the framework
     */
    public Chapter convert(String chapterId) {
        return  service.findChapter(Integer.parseInt(chapterId));
    }
}
```

How you go about registering this depends on your config. However assuming Java code config then:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "..." })
public class MvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

    //other configuration

    @Override
    public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry formatterRegistry) {
        formatterRegistry.addConverter(getChapterConverter());
    }

    @Bean
    public StringToChapterConverter getChapterConverter(){
        return new StringToChapterConverter();
    }
}
```

So, now with the above in place when a request is made which is bound to a Chapter object the framework will look to see if a suitable converter has been defined for the Chapter type and then call the corresponding convert(String source) which enables you to return the instance from your database or wherever.

See further:

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#core-convert

Comment: Thanks Alan for the hint, I was missing the converter part, will check and I hope it will work.

Comment: Alan's suggestion SOLVED my issue.